# Facebook Private Messages From Graph API Marked As Spam

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to reply to a user's Private Messages sent to a page as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations. The reply is created successfully and can be seen in the page admin's Inbox but shows as 'This message is no longer available because it was identified as abusive or marked as spam.' in the user's Inbox. This is the case regardless of the friendship status between the page and the user. I can't find any way of un-marking the message in the user's Inbox. What do I need to do to correctly show the message in the user's Inbox?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Are you posting links in your messages and/or are the messages almost identical to each other? If so it sounds like this is all working as expected

Comment: No links and I'd say the messages have been suitably different.